# Sort an array of objects dynamically javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I am having an array with the below items. I need to sort the below array to the array that is shown in sorted items,so that all the value with the rules can be together and the ELIG_DATABASE should be grouped with the ELIG_SERVICE.

```
 const items =[{"name":"ELIG_DATABASE","ready":true},
               {"name":"ELIG_RULES_SERVICE","ready":true},                   
               {"name":"ELIG_GATEWAY","ready":true}, 
               {"name":"ELIG_GATEWAY_LATEST","ready":true,"latest":true}, 
               {"name":"ELIG_SERVICE_LATEST","ready":true,"latest":true}, 
               {"name":"ELIG_SERVICE","ready":true}, 
               {"name":"HDXTS","ready":false},
               {"name":"RULES_VERSION","ready":true},];
```

I want to achieve this array so that values in the name property that has rules can be together,gateway things should be together, elig service thing should be together just that  ELIG_DATABASE should be  grouped together with elig service and then all other values in the name property can be sorted alphabetically.

```
         const sortedItems =[
               {"name":"ELIG_GATEWAY","ready":true},                    
            {"name":"ELIG_GATEWAY_LATEST","ready":true,"latest":true}, 
               {"name":"ELIG_RULES_SERVICE","ready":true},
               {"name":"RULES_VERSION","ready":true},
               {"name":"ELIG_DATABASE","ready":true},
               {"name":"ELIG_SERVICE_LATEST","ready":true,"latest":true}, 
               {"name":"ELIG_SERVICE","ready":true}, 
               {"name":"HDXTS","ready":false}
               ];
```

I tried using this code but that sorts alphabetically putting ELIG_DATABASE in first position.Could any one please help on how to achieve this array in minimum code as possible.

```
             items.sort((svcA, svcB) => {
             const serviceA = svcA.name.toUpperCase();
             const serviceB = svcB.name.toUpperCase();
             return serviceA.localeCompare(serviceB);
                });
```

Comment: do you have a wanted result?

Comment: It seems you do not have a proper  comparison  logic

Comment: No the array is dynamic, it can have any number of objects with different values in the name property,all other propertes that is coming need to be sorted alphabetically just that values in the name property that has rules ,like rules_version and elig_rules should be grouped together.And elig_database should be grouped with elig_service or elig_service_latest,values that has gateway should be grouped together

Comment: @Asutosh it does have a comparison logic with values in the name property that has rules should be together, values that  has gateway should be together,values that has elig service should be together along with elig database

Comment: I am afraid to solve this using sort, rather I would create multiple arrays based upon your grouping logic (each array for your group) and join those arrays to get the final result.

Comment: I don't understand why RULES_VERSION need to be so high, is it ok if it ends up at the bottom ? Otherwise, I don't understand what is your algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the wanted groups first in an array, sort the data and assign the object to the group or to the end of a temp array and get the flat data as result.

```js
var data = [{ name: "ELIG_DATABASE", ready: true }, { name: "ELIG_RULES_SERVICE", ready: true }, { name: "ELIG_GATEWAY", ready: true }, { name: "ELIG_GATEWAY_LATEST", ready: true, latest: true }, { name: "ELIG_SERVICE_LATEST", ready: true, latest: true }, { name: "ELIG_SERVICE", ready: true }, { name: "HDXTS", ready: false }, { name: "RULES_VERSION", ready: true }],
    together = [['GATEWAY'], ['RULES'], ['ELIG_DATABASE', 'ELIG_SERVICE']],
    groups = { GATEWAY: [], RULES: [], ELIG_DATABASE: [] },
    temp = [groups.GATEWAY, groups.RULES, groups.ELIG_DATABASE],
    result;

for (let o of data.sort(({ name: a }, { name: b }) => a.localeCompare(b))) {
    let target = together.find(a => a.some(v => o.name.includes(v)));
    if (target) groups[target[0]].push(o);
    else temp.push(o);
}

result = temp.flat();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```